# Any way to emulate object-safe "Clone"?

Tags: rust

I'm not sure what the design pattern is called, but I have an immutable data structure S with a async method called `update` that returns `Result<Self>` (basically clones self & applies the updates represented by the method arguments). I want to move this `update` routine into a trait but I'm running into problems because there's various places where the trait is required to be object-safe but obviously `Self` in the return type isn't object safe.

The goal of "traitifying" this method is I want to refer to the trait in various places so that I can swap out the implementation in-use without the rest of the code caring.

I'm guessing this is what existential types might solve but I'm curious if there's a way to trait-ify my code today. I'm happy to restructure `S` however needed if I'm not doing things in a "rusty" way, but I'm wondering if this is just impossible in today's Rust :.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to return a `Box<dyn YourTrait>` rather than an actual `Self`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the method on the trait but don't care about calling the method on trait objects, you can explicitly omit the method in question from trait objects with the `Self: Sized` constraint.

```
trait MyTrait {
  // ... Other object-safe methods
  fn update(&self) -> Result<Self> where Self: Sized;
}
```

The `Self: Sized` constraint explicitly opts out of dynamic dispatch and removes that method from the trait objects.

If you *do* need it to be in the trait objects, you'll need to get a bit creative. Trait objects can't return `Self`, so you'll have to get a bit clever. The [`dyn-clone`](https://github.com/dtolnay/dyn-clone) crate does this for the `Clone` trait, but it uses macros to glue everything together. I'm not sure if there's a way around using macros for this sort of thing, in full generality.

Comment: If you need just one trait you don't need macros.

Answer (score 1):

Silvio's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78050717/180697) is correct but for posterity I went with a slightly different approach. I split the immutable parts into 1 trait and the mutation parts into a separate trait:

```
trait ImmutableTrait {}

trait TraitOwner {
  async fn update(&self) -> Result<Rc<dyn ImmutableTrait>>
}
```

Then in the write path, the various functions accepts a `& impl TraitOwner` which means I don't need the `update` piece to be object-safe. To actually publish the update, the traits are slightly different:

```
trait ImmutableTrait: std::any::Any {}

trait TraitOwner {
   async fn update(&self) -> Result<Rc<dyn ImmutableTrait>>;
   fn replace_active(self: &mut Rc<Self>, snapshot: Rc<dyn ImmutableTrait>);
}

struct Foo {}
impl ImmutableTrait for Foo {}
impl TraitOwner for Foo {
  async fn update(&self) -> Result<Rc<dyn ImmutableTrait>> { todo!() }
  fn replace_active(self: &mut Rc<Self>, snapshot: Rc<dyn ImmutableTrait>) {
    if snapshot.type_id() == TypeId::of::<Foo>() {
       snapshot = unsafe {
         Rc::from_raw(Rc::into_raw(snapshot) as *const Foo)
       };
       *self = snapshot;
    } else {
       panic!("Invalid snapshot type provided to replace Foo");
    }
  }
}
```

This could have been 1 trait (using the `where Self: Sized`) to opt-out the relevant functions or trait inheritance where `TraitOwner: ImmutableTrait` but for my application it made sense to split `TraitOwner` into a disjoint trait graph at the cost of weird `Any` hoop jumping to make the situation easier when `TraitOwner` and `ImmutableTrait` are the same concrete object (probably indicates some leaky abstraction that it's ever the same object).

Comment: This looks like a convoluted way to opt-out methods for object safety, i.e. `where Self: Sized`, with no benefit.